# Denormalizing entities for binding to a grid?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, devexpress, poco

I've got two tables in SQL Server, say A and B. B is a list of documents, and A contains data indicating whether a project should include a row in B.

```
A
___________
AId int PK,
BId int,
Include bit

B
___________
BId int PK,
BDocNumber varchar(10),
BName varchar(128)
```

I have POCOs for A and B, but ultimately what I'm after is something I can bind to a devExpress grid that contains the data from both (BDocNumber, BName, Include)

1. I can set up B as a navigation property, but I don't know a way to flatten that out for the grid (DevExpress ASPxGridView, server mode)
2. I've also looked into entity splitting, but it appears that won't work since I want to join on BId instead of AId.

A solution to either 1 or 2 is acceptable, but learning about both would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a "has-a" relationship or a one-to-one navigation property in A to B that you want to access in your DevExpress Grid. You can do this by setting your FieldName property to your NavigationProperty.FieldName

Say for a one-to-one relationship of Persont to Address like the following:

```
    public class Person
    {

      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
      public string City { get; set; }
      public string State { get; set; }
      public string Zip { get; set; }

     }
```

Your GridView in your aspx page to include both the Person and the StreeAddress property of the Address navigation property would look like this

```
        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="FirstName" VisibleIndex="0">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="LastName" VisibleIndex="1">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Address.StreetAddress" VisibleIndex="1">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        </Columns>
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

In this case, Person being table A and Address being table B. You are binding your gridview on A so then you would be setting your field name to B.FieldToDisplay.

Hope this helps!